# Querying database vs Querying IQueryable in order to create auto-complete functionality

Tags: c#, database, performance, linq, iqueryable

I have a texbox control in my wpf application where I will like to get a auto complete listbox as the user types in. In other words I have something like google's search box:

[image]

---

**I have managed to do that in two ways and I will like to know which one is more efficient.**

### First way:

As user types into the textbox every time the texbox changes I update the listbox by quering the database. therefore I have something like:

```
void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        // new text
        var content = ((TextBox)sender).Text;

        // I am selecting the posible items using ado.net
        var posibleItems= PdvEntities.Entities.TableFoos.Where(TableFoo=> TableFoo.Description.Contains(content)).Select(c=>c);


        listbox1.ItemsSource = posibleItems;
}
```

note that with this approach I will be querying the database every time a keyup event fires on that textbox.

### Second way:

Instead of querying the database everytime the keyup event fires, I do the following:

```
// select all items and store that as a global variable
IQueryable allItems = PdvEntities.Entities.TableFoos.Select(a => a);


void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        // new text
        var content = ((TextBox)sender).Text;

        // I don't have the code but I will then filter variable 
        // allItems based if their description contains 'content'

        // pseudo code
        newFileter <- filter of allItems that contain content


        listbox1.ItemsSource = newFileter;
}
```

not that in this case I query the database just once and everytime I need to add items to the listbox I will query a IQueryable variable instead of the database. I am afraid that if the database is to big this technique will consume a lot of memory.

---

Also I forgot to mention that the database may not be local. Right now I am connecting to the database locally but this application may run with a remote database connection.  Which approach is more efficient?

Comment: You are aware that you sue IQueryable in BOTH cases?

Comment: yeah I am confused. I guess I will have to iterate through allItems in a for loop so that linq executes the query right? I guess I am missing that step. If I where to perform that step I believe that on the 'second way' (second method) linq will not query the database and maybe it will be more efficient.

Comment: No Idea how you have `PdvEntities.`*Entities*

Comment: You have both versions of the code. Why are you asking us which one is more efficient? Run both of them and measure it! That's the only way to be sure, we can only guess.

Comment: Is cause the database is small for performing tests and I will have to simulate in remote computers and I always learn a lot from asking questions in here. But yeah you are right I will test it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There won't be any significant difference between the two versions. That's because the following code doesn't do what you think it does:

```
// select all items and store that as a global variable
IQueryable allItems = PdvEntities.Entities.TableFoos.Select(a => a);
```

It doesn't “store” all items in the field, it doesn't even go to the database at all. It's just a query that can retrieve all the items if you iterate it.

On the other hand, if you did something like

```
Foo[] allItems = PdvEntities.Entities.TableFoos.ToArray();
```

that would actually retrieve all items into memory. But there's no way of knowing which one will be more efficient, if we don't know everything about your database and your execution environment.

Answer (score 1):

If your `PdvEntities` class is an EntityFramework Context then the following is a Linq-to-Entities query which will generate T-SQL against your database and get only your filtered items.

```
var posibleItems= PdvEntities.Entities.TableFoos
  .Where(TableFoo=> TableFoo.Description.Contains(content)).Select(c=>c);
```

Not sure I understand your other solution. As @svik mentions You could use `ToArray()` and `ToList()` to get all you items in memory, but this isn't going to perfomant at all.

It looks like you need to throttle calls to your database, so as the use types, every `n` seconds you send a query with the filter.

Have a look at [system.reactive](/questions/tagged/system.reactive). It will allow you throttle your keyup event in a nice way.

I wrote an article on this here:
http://www.gideondsouza.com/blog/implementing-simple-instant-search-with-rx-reactive-extensions (Which is about just throttling a search)

And then another one which talks about linq-to-entities to throttle a database search:
http://www.gideondsouza.com/blog/abstracting-reactive-extensions-for-sql-server-compact-and-implementing-an-instant-search

---

Based on the stuff I've written in my articles you could do something like this:

You'll need a little helper

```
public class ObservableHelper<T>
    where T : class //or EntityObject 
{
    public ObservableHelper()
    {
        _dat = new PdvEntities();
    }
    PdvEntities _dat;
    public IObservable<IList<T>> GetAllAsObservables
                                (Func<PdvEntities, IQueryable<T>> funcquery)
    {
        var getall = Observable.ToAsync<PdvEntities, IQueryable<T>>(funcquery);
        return getall(_dat).Select(x => x.ToList());
    }
}
```

**Then** in your form:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //your playing with IQueryable<TableFoos>
    _repo = new ObservableHelper<TableFoos>()

    Observable.FromEventPattern(h => textBox1.KeyUp += h,
                           h => textBox1.KeyUp -= h)//tell Rx about our event
        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), cs)///throttle
        .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Dispatcher);//so we have no cross threading issues
        .Do(a => SearchList(textBox1.Text))//do this method 
        .Subscribe();
}

IObservableHelper<TableFoos, PdvEntities> _repo;

void SearchList(string query)
{//AS MANY keystrokes are there, this function will be called only
 // once every 500 milliseconds..

    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    listBox1.BeginUpdate();
    var getfn = _repo.GetAllAsObservables
        (d => d.TableFoos.Where(c => c.TableFoos.Contains(query)));
    getfn.ObserveOn(this).Subscribe(resultList => //is an IList<TableFoos>
        {
            foreach (var item in resultList)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(...
            }
            listBox1.EndUpdate();
        });
}
```

Comment: when I execute that statement I will be querying the database. I am not sure if I am still querying the database with the second technique. I want to know which one is more efficient. thanks for the help

Comment: You will still have to query your database in the end. Not sure what you mean to do in the second method.

Comment: Maybe I am explaining my self incorrectly. what am I saying is to query the database once and place all those records in memory. that way the sond time I need data I will be querying a variable and not the database. I guess I will be able to achieve this by iterating through all the items in the IQueryable variable in a foreach loop. sorry for not explaining my self clearly

Comment: It seems to me that this answer doesn't actually actually answer the question. RX might be useful, but it's not what the question is about.

Comment: @svick yes true, but from what the OP is asking it seems he is going to implement instant search, I was trying to sorta explain how he could use RX to his advantage.

Comment: @TonoNam yes I didn't answer your question fully but wanted to point out a possible solution you could use :)

Comment: @gideon, awesome, except SO is not a discussion forum. It's a Q&A site and you did not actually answer the question.

Comment: @gideon I did not wrote that comment thanks for the help though. I actually voted up on your answer...